# Dynamic to static url Add another parameter

Tags: .htaccess

i have this htaccess code for converting dynamic url to static url

```
RewriteRule ^dogs/([^/.]+)$ dogs/index.php?county=$1 [L]
```

it works ok, when i test it using http://example.com/dogs/Avon

but I wanted to add another parameter ie http://example.com/dogs/Avon/2

I tried this but it doesnt work.

```
RewriteRule ^dogs/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ dogs/index.php?county=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Need some help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
RewriteRule ^dogs/([0-9a-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ dogs/index.php?county=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

I think that is for the type number.